# ngFor over object instead of array?

Tags: javascript, angular, api

Receiving this error in console:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

services.ts

```
      private url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=SNAP,fb,AIG%2b,GOOG,AAPL,AMZN&types=quote";

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getCID(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
      }
```

component.ts

```
      ngOnInit() {
        this.svc.getCID().subscribe(data => {
          this.cidData = data;
          console.log(data);
        });
```

component.html

```
    <div *ngIf="cidData">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let x of cidData">
          <a routerLink="/companydetails/{{x.symbol}}">{{x.symbol}}</a>
```

API call gives

```
    {"GOOG":{"quote":{"symbol":"GOOG","companyName":"Alphabet Inc."}}, "SNAP":{etc...}
```

I think the issue is that cidData is not an array, but I'm not really sure how to return it as an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using angular version 6 then you can use the built-in pipe keyvalue to iterate through objects

```
 <li *ngFor="let x of cidData | keyvalue">
      <a routerLink="/companydetails/{{x.value.quote.symbol}}">{{x.value.quote.symbol}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

to turn your object into an array by Object.values(obj), you can see [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/)

```js
// object with your example here
    ngOnInit() {
        this.svc.getCID().subscribe(data => {
            this.cidData = data;
            let array = 
            Object.values(this.cidData.GOOD) 
            // here you have an array    
            console.log(array);
   });
```

Comment: normally with a single object, otherwise it must be a table the response if there is more object